# PocketSocket websocket error code 1002

Tags: ios, objective-c, node.js, websocket

I've been using the [PocketSocket](https://github.com/zwopple/PocketSocket) library to connect to a Node.js websocket server, it works perfectly but lately I've been noticing that clients sometimes disconnect automatically and get the 1002 error code.

Has anyone been experiencing this before? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: No, PocketSocket works fine for me. Could you share more details?

Comment: I fixed the error, I needed to split the data in different "frames". The message I was sending was too big.

Comment: @Carloc C, hm, I thought WebSocket will do this. What was the side of the message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed.

The message I was trying to send was really big.

I fixed it by splitting the message in multiple sub-messages and sending them separately.